# Progress bar for copying one directory include all sub directories and files in windows form application

Tags: winforms, progress-bar

I'm  copying a one directory(include all sub directories and files) present in one drive into another drive with same names for that I want to show a Progress bar i have seen so many examples with timers but i dont know how much time that will take so please guide me how to achieve that

I written the code like this

```
 private void btnDriveSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        ErrorProvider errorproviderDrive = new ErrorProvider();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbDrive.Text))
        {
            if (tbDrive.TextLength == 1)
            {
                drive = tbDrive.Text;
                string org1 = Application.StartupPath + "\\UserFirstDetails.xml";
                UsrDetails.Load(org1);
                XmlNode drivetag = UsrDetails.SelectSingleNode("UserFirstDetails/Drive");
                drivetag.InnerText = drive;

                FileInfo fp = new FileInfo(org1);
                fp.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
                UsrDetails.Save(org1);

                DirectoryInfo diSource = new DirectoryInfo(sourcedrive+"Palle_University");
                DirectoryInfo diTarget = new DirectoryInfo(tbDrive.Text+":\\Palle_University");

                CopyAll(diSource, diTarget);
                this.Hide();
            }
            else 
            {
                errorproviderDrive.SetError(tbDrive, "Length should be one character only");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            errorproviderDrive.SetError(tbDrive, "Drive Should not be empty");
        }
    }


 public  void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
    {

        DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);
        // Copy each file into the new directory.
        foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Copying {0}\{1}", target.FullName, fi.Name);
            fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, fi.Name), true);
        }

        // Copy each subdirectory using recursion.
        foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceSubDir in source.GetDirectories())
        {
            DirectoryInfo nextTargetSubDir =
                target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceSubDir.Name);
            CopyAll(diSourceSubDir, nextTargetSubDir);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just use the [built-in copy progress animation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the progress of files copy operation to display in a progressbar control, you need to get the total number of files in the source directory

First declare two general variables

```
int totalFilescount; //Total number of files in the source directory
int currentFileindex; //Incremented when a file is copied to the destination directory
```

Before calling CopyAll, you need to get the total number of files in the source dir

```
    totalFilescount = diSource.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
```

In CopyAll method, for each file copied you increment currentFileindex, then you can calculate progress using the following

```
     double progressVal = (double)(currentFileindex * 100 )/ totalFilescount;
```

Modified CopyAll method to report progress

```
public void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
{

    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);
    // Copy each file into the new directory.

    foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"Copying {0}\{1}", target.FullName, fi.Name);
        fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, fi.Name), true);
        currentFileindex += 1;

     double progressVal = (double)(currentFileindex * 100 )/ totalFilescount;

    if (progressVal <= 100)
    {
        progressBar1.Value =Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(progressVal));
    }

    }

    // Copy each subdirectory using recursion.
    foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceSubDir in source.GetDirectories())
    {
        DirectoryInfo nextTargetSubDir =
            target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceSubDir.Name);
        CopyAll(diSourceSubDir, nextTargetSubDir);
    }
}
```

Comment: very well written. Kudos!

Comment: I tried your code but progress bar is not showing, can i have change any  properties of progress bar